# usb.core.USBError: [Errno 5] Input/Output Error

Tags: python, hid, libusb, pyusb

Description:
Trying to read mouse data with below code but getting error as given below. please help if anyone has gone through same issue.purpose of doing this is i have read data from the device which is connected as HID device so by the time trying  with mouse.

CODE:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import sys
import usb.backend.libusb1

Vendor_ID = 0x0461
Product_ID =0x4E22

dev=usb.core.find(idVendor=Vendor_ID,idProduct=Product_ID)

if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('device not found')
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print("Device Found")
    usb.util.claim_interface(dev,0)
    dev=usb.core.find(idVendor=Vendor_ID,idProduct=Product_ID)

try:
   dev.set_configuration()
   print ("Configuration set")

except:
  print("configuration not set")

data =dev.read(0x81,4)
print(data)

usb.util.release_interface(dev, 0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Device Found
    Configuration set
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "USB_Read.py", line 27, in <module>
    data =dev.read(0x81,4)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 983, in read
    ret = fn(
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 846, in intr_read
    return self.__read(self.lib.libusb_interrupt_transfer,
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 936, in __read
    _check(retval)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
    usb.core.USBError: [Errno 5] Input/Output Error
```

Comment: If the mouse is under control of a driver you will not be able to access it directly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue for a lab power supply. Did you find a solution? I checked with `dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0)`, which is false in my case. So @KlausD., this does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `LIBUSB_DEBUG` like this:

```
sudo env LIBUSB_DEBUG=1  python USB_Read.py
```

you get more information that may help solving the problem.

Well I fixed

```
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 5] Input/Output Error
```

like this.
Go to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and create a file `Primax.rules`
with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",        ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", MODE="0666"
```

Note you need to change that `0461` (what is the vendorID of Primax) to the one of you're device.
(...or just entirely kick out that ATTRS..., part)

so before it looked like this:
(Note i was targeting Bus 003 Device 022)

```
cd /dev/bus/usb/003
ls -l

crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 256 18. Mär 15:38 001
c--------- 1 root root 189, 276 18. Mär 15:25 022
```

after the change with the rules file and (re-Plug Device):

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 256 18. Mär 15:38 001
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 189, 278 18. Mär 15:56 022
```